# Displacement button after running in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Im develop one xml with some button,Its fine show in xml view https://www.dropbox.com/s/ao893440404e2gk/Untitled-1.png and emulator but Displacement button in my device(galaxy fit android2.3.6)https://www.dropbox.com/s/ux5st3x51q10p21/Untitled-2.png

what can i do?

this is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/back1"
android:gravity="clip_vertical"
tools:context=".Main" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:background="@null"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/btnmain2" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:background="@null"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/btnmain3" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="126dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/btnmain1" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/btnmain4" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe i misunderstood you, but if your goal is to position all your buttons to the center (independt from the screen resolution):

```
<RelativeLayout 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout 
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content">
          <Button/>
          <Button/>
          <Button/>
          <Button/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So that all your buttons will be aligned to the center in the `RelativeLayout` in the containing `LinearLayout`

I Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is working exactly as you designed it.  The problem comes from button1 where you specify the top margin in dips `android:layout_marginTop="126dp"` instead of vertical centering.  A better solution is to create an empty 0 height View (or similar basic element) with vertical centering that you then base the other buttons around.  For example:

You have:

```
+----------------+
|                |
|    (button)    |
|    (button)    |
|    (button)    |
|    (button)    |
|                |
+----------------+
```

What I am suggesting:

```
+----------------+
|                |
|    (button)    |
|    (button)    |
|     (View)     |
|    (button)    |
|    (button)    |
|                |
+----------------+
```